# Getting types generated similar to apollo codegen from graphql-codegen

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-codegen

I am new to apollo and graphql. I tried using both [apollo-codegen](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-clientcodegen-output) and [graphql-codegen](https://graphql-code-generator.com/) and I want all the types generated in one single file like in graphql-codegen , but in apollo it creates multiple files.

The issue I am having while using graphql-codegen is the type generated is not the format that I get data.

While using apollo client useQuery the data I get from backend is in format of

```
data: {
  queryName : {... actualDataObject }

}
```

SO the output for a sample query by apollo -codegen is : -

```
export interface Login_logIn {
  __typename: "UserPayload";
  email: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
}

export interface Login {
  logIn: Login_logIn;  // logIn is the queryname here
}
```

But using graphql-codegent the output I get is : -

```
export type UserPayload = {
  __typename?: 'UserPayload';
  _id: Scalars['ID'];
  email: Scalars['String'];
  firstname: Scalars['String'];
  lastname: Scalars['String'];
};
```

Is it possible to get graphql-codegen out put similar to apollo codegen i.e in format of: -

```
export type UserPayload {
  logIn : {                     //logIn is the queryname
    __typename?: 'UserPayload';
    _id: Scalars['ID'];
    email: Scalars['String'];
    firstname: Scalars['String'];
    lastname: Scalars['String'];
 }
}
```

So that it becomes easy to use in useQuery or useMutation hook ? By using graphql-codegen

```
 const [doLogin, {loading, error, data}] = useMutation<UserPayload, UserInputVariables>(
    LOGIN,
    {
      variables: {
        ...variables,
      }
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `typescript-operations` plugin to your `codegen.yml`:

```
generates:
  types.ts:
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
```

and make sure you've set the `documents` property to point to where your queries are located.

This will generate two additional types per operation -- one for the query response and one for the variables -- both of which can then be passed to your hook.

```
export type LoginMutationVariables = Exact<{ ... }>;


export type LoginMutation = (
  { __typename?: 'Mutation' }
  & { logIn: ... }
);
```

You can see additional details about the plugin [here](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-operations). If you're using Apollo, you might consider having codegen just [generate the hooks for you](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-react-apollo) instead.

Comment: I was not using codegen to create hooks, So was not adding documents property to codegen.yml. Your answer solved the issue and created types that I needed .. Thankyou.